# Bootstrap: Changing Grid Dimensions

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, grid

I have a container of rows that I'd like to make the container bigger.  By default, bootstrap has it at 1200px.  I thought that by changing col-md-4 to something like col-lg-4, it would expand the grid but it doesn't for me.  Is there a way to expand the grid?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't want to mess around with less variables and just want to increase your container size...make sure your custom css style sheet is called after your bootstrap css so that it isn't overridden and then use a simple css markup in your style sheet such as

```
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
.container{
    width: 1400px;
}
```

You could even use min-width/max-width properties, or as benja pointed out you could also use container-fluid to maximize your container to the full width of the viewport.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `<div class="container-fluid">` for a container that will take the full width of your viewport.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the [Customize](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/) menu on Bootstrap website and choose your preferred size. In `Less Variables -> Grid system` you can find a form to input your preferred sizes. Then you can easily download the preferred grid. Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

The middle term in `col-XX-num` corresponds to the screen size that will cause a "break" in your grid so that the items in the grid are responsive. For example, a div with a class of `col-sm-4` will take up 4 of the 12 grid cells in a default Bootstrap `row` until the "small" screen size is noted (in Bootstrap "small" is defined as 750px). [Read more about the Bootstrap grid](http://getbootstrap.com/css/).

If you want to change the `width` of the Bootstrap `container`, use this CSS:

```
.container{
    max-width: 1900px;
}
```

This will make the container wider but will not make your grid bigger. The Bootstrap grid is locked at 12 cells per row. When you use the class `col-md-4` as you gave in your example, you are telling Bootstrap to make this element take up 4 out of a possible 12 cells in this row.

Perhaps you will achieve your desired result making your columns take up less cells. Something like `col-md-2` then you can use something like `col-md-offset-2` to position the column within the row if needed.

Hope this helps!